Can I use a React Component as a Keycloak call back?
I would like to use a Keycloak server to secure my React application.
I am using the keycloak-js package in my React Application.
The server redirected the browser to the dedicated URL(i.e. http://localhost:3000/testCallBack#state=b7db9a8c-9eae-4046-bf3c-b3ef1f7e0ec4&session_state=a203e7e0-fd17-43c1-97ef-6b0d12a6f514&code=3d2a8e8e-0507-42ae-93cf-05fc3cabe574.a203e7e0-fd17-43c1-97ef-6b0d12a6f514.4c1ce54a-3b50-4473-a147-b6acf131fac0).
However, I don't know how to get the "code" in my React component.
Here is my code:
App.jsx
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import TestLogin from './TestLogin.jsx';
import TestCallBack from '../TestCallBack.jsx';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<TestLogin />} />
        <Route path='/testCallBack' element={<TestCallBack />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

TestLogin.jsx
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
export default function TestLogin(){
  const keycloak = new Keycloak({
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        url: "keycloak.servers",
        realm: "master",
        clientId: "myAppId"
      });
      useEffect(() => {
        let doLogin = async () => {
          try {
            const authenticated = await keycloak.init();
            const link=await keycloak.login({
                redirectUri:"http://localhost:3000/testCallBack"
            });
            
            if (authenticated) {
              console.log('User is authenticated');
            } else {
              console.log('User is not authenticated');
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to initialize adapter:', error);
          }
        }    
        doLogin();
      });
    return <div></div>
}

TestCallBack.jsx
export default function TestCallBack(){
    return <span>Hi</span>
}


The easiest way is to use implicit authentication flow that will automaticcaly set token without needing to exchange authorization code for access token

Would you tell me how to use the implicit authentication?

Give me a second. I will write full answer. Also my previous comment was slightly wrong

I have found this code on github that specifically use keycloak-js. The tokens should be automatically set after successful login and can be accessed via keycloak object in js. In readme of repo you can find also youtube tutorial. https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo/blob/main/src/services/UserService.js

I follow the part1 video, I got "JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided" error.

First you have to make sure, that you use implicit flow, since it is easiest to setup. The only downside it is slightly less secure, since the token can be leaked, if someone listens for urls.
Implicit flow will return the token in url
    https://your-app.com/callback#
id_token=eyJhbsInRVCJ9...
&access_token=slkjLKDF098...

In the url you will recieve multiple tokens including id token, which contains information about user or access token which contain information about permissions of user.
Keycloak use openid standart, what means you can read more about what is returned in redirecr url by reading openid specification.
If you want to know how to setup implicit flow along with nice explanation of auth flow you can follow this tutorial
